# RSpec error "undefined method 'respond_to' for Rspec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm having a bug that I can't seem to pinpoint. I have an existing project that I'm adding tests to. When I try running my test (just a simple test... build a User with FactoryGirl, and calling "should respond_to(:email)"), I get the following error:

```
1) User should have an email
   Failure/Error: should respond_to(:email)
   NoMethodError:
     undefined method 'respond_to' for #<Rspec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3:0x00000008355590>
   # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:7:in 'block(2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have a gist with my code in it here:
https://gist.github.com/jeffstagg/9477647

I've got another project on the same dev box that runs rspec tests just fine, though I built it with my tests first and started the project with rspec / capybara / guard in mind. This project I'm coming back to later, and apparently missed something when setting up rspec for it. Can anyone see where I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to trigger RSpec's predicate matcher, which requires you write it as `be_predicate`, eg.

`cat.can_has_cheezeburger?` becomes `cat.should be_can_has_cheezburger?`

Sometimes these end up very readable, e.g. `.too_big?` => `should be_too_big`. Other times they don't quite work, like `.respond_to?` => `should be_respond_to`.

For such cases you're better off just using `.respond_to?.should be_true`

Answer (score 0):

Add below to your rails_helper.rb(spec/support/rails_helper.rb) file:

*

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

*